# How to use JSoup to connect to URL with hashtag #

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to use JSoup to connect to a page with hashtag (#) i.e.

http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances/zgbs/appliances/ref=zg_bs_nav_0#5

But it ignores the # part and connects to http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Appliances/zgbs/appliances/ref=zg_bs_nav_0

How do I connect to the url with hashtag?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - hashtag is not sent along with `HTTP` request to server.

It is handled by browsers and was originally used to automatically scroll user's window to given part of a long page ([see "HTML Links - Create a Bookmark" in w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)).

Nowadays it is becoming more popular to use hashtag to navigate between subpages using `JavaScript` as these scripts are executed in user's browser and can easily access hashtag value.

Amazon uses its value in similar manner, so it is `JavaScript` what creates dynamic requests and fetches data according to hashtag value.

Coming back to `jsoup` - is just `HTML` parser, nothing more. It cannot execute `JavaScript` code. To make it work you can either try to lookup what requests `JavaScript` on this page sends or just try using browser emulator such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) or [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).